# I have an existing ERC721A smart contract deployed but I feel there's some error in the contract. Please help!

Tags: tokens, etherscan, nft, erc-721, mint

My team and I deployed an ERC721A smart contract months ago and we need to use that contract again when we try to mint 1 NFT it shows normal gas fees but when we try to mint more than one it shows 1.2 or more ETH as gas fees. Since it's ERC721A it should show gas fees the same for 1 or for 4. Please check the contract and you can let us know, what is the issue and error there.

It'll be great if you can just help us with this since it's really important. Thank you!
The contract link - https://etherscan.io/address/0x6358f271817b890d64b66574d7e7061142e4f31b#writeContract